# HTML ID attribute in close tag?

Tags: html, css

Is this code okay, where I ID a close div:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">

</div id=main">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @Purmou - I can only assume OP wanted to signify which div was being closed, for readability purposes.

Answer (score 11):

No. The `id` attribute should only be in the opening tag.

If you're doing this for readability, you might want to use HTML comments and tabified source:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">

        </div>
        <!-- close main div -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 but the whole truth is scarier: not only the `id` attribute.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker - True. No attributes should ever be in the closing tag.

Answer (score 4):

It's invalid: The [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will output

> Line x, Column y: End tag had attributes.

If you want to do this to avoid confusion from multiple closing tags, just use a comment to clarify which tag belongs to which element:

```
</div> <!-- #main -->
```

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid syntax in all markup languages <sub>that I know of</sub>.
Closing tags cannot have attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, It's invalid. but you could do something like this if it's readability you're after.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">

        </div><!-- end of main -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently having to perform maintenance on older code, I found that using comments at the end of a div tag really made it difficult to comment out large sections of code thanks to HTML not having nestable comment tags. So, I got into the habit of modifying the comments into hidden spans at the end of large block divs.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="dialog_edit_group">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...HTML content here...
        </div><span title=".modal-content" HIDDEN></span>
    </div><span title=".modal-dialog" HIDDEN></span>
</div><span title=".modal #dialog_edit_group" HIDDEN></span>
<!--
<div class="modal fade" id="dialog_edit_group_OLD">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...HTML content here...
        </div><span title=".modal-content" HIDDEN></span>
    </div><span title=".modal-dialog" HIDDEN></span>
</div><span title=".modal #dialog_edit_group_OLD" HIDDEN></span>
-->
```

I put the "HIDDEN" HTML5 attribute in there so if others modify it and add text for some reason, the contents will usually stay hidden. I made it ALL CAPS so that it would stand out a bit more as if to shout "COMMENT HERE!". Yes, it does create a DOM element that now has to be maintained by the browser, but its a small price to pay during heavy active website development.

Using "end div comments" as such conforms to the HTML standard, gives me greater readability and allows me to use the HTML comment tag to disable large blocks of the page to aid in development. Maybe it will be useful for others as well.